# Why does a zero translate transform affect the position of a background image in a cloned node?

Tags: javascript, css

In the code below, a deep clone is created of `#outerDiv`. After adding the clone to the DOM, a zero translate `transform` is applied to the clone. Now, even though the CSS property `background-attachment` is set to `fixed`, the position of the `background-image` in `#secondInnerDiv` in the clone somehow changes. Why does this happen, and more importantly, how do I prevent this from happening?

```js
function createClone() {
  const clonedDiv = document.querySelector("#outerDiv").cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(clonedDiv);
  clonedDiv.style.setProperty("transform", "translate(0, 0)");
  console.log("Cloned and appended");
}
```

```css
#outerDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 60vh;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url("https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png");
  background-size: 80vw;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#firstInnerDiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 40vh;
  bottom: 10vh;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

#secondInnerDiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 40vh;
  bottom: 10vh;
  right: 5vw;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url("https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png");
  background-size: 80vw;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
  <input type="button" value="Clone" onclick="createClone()" />
  <div id="firstInnerDiv">
  </div>
  <div id="secondInnerDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the reference for "fixed" is no more the same. Your only way is to remove translate(). If you cannot then it's not possible

Comment: @TemaniAfif But why is this the case — `fixed` should measure things relative to the viewport? Applying a (zero) translate transform to the original `#outerDiv` (i.e. not its clone) does not cause any problems. Why does the clone behave differently?

Comment: *fixed should measure things relative to the viewport?* --> not always, transform will move the reference from viewport to the transformed element. It's by design.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see, thanks. However, I'm still confused why a transform applied to the original node does _not_ move the reference (replace `clonedDiv.style` by `document.querySelector("#outerDiv").style` in the JS code above).

Comment: it does move but your element is already at the top/left of the screen so you won't notice any difference. Both references are above each other. Move the element a little and you will see the difference